# How to find the continuous duplicates in a list in python

Tags: python

For example : if my list is

```
a = [1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1]
```

1. For loop should be started(at value 1) and stopped when the new
   value is encountered so here it should stop before 0 and print the first
   and last position`[1,1]`
2. Next the loop should continue till the next value is reached and print the first and last position`[0,0]`
3. Likewise it should be continued till the end of the list and print the new_list

I would like to get the:

```
new_list = [1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1]
```

can anyone suggest a way to do this?

Comment: First of all new_list should contain occurrences or indexes? Secondly, what have you tried?

Comment: so `[1,0,1,0]` should become `[1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0]` ?

Comment: It's not like that. For example, in this list [1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1] it should check the duplicate of  value of '1' till a new values is encountered so there are four 1's so it should print only first and last 1 like [1,1].    e.g., if [1,1,1,1] - [1,1]  if [1,1,1] -[1,1]   if [1,1]-[1,1]  if [1]- [1] like this so whatever the number of duplicates always the first and last value. same loop should continue for the new value too.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> a = [1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1]
>>> [num for k, g in groupby(a) for num in list(g)[:2]]
[1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1]
```

Comment: This works. But if the value '1' is present only once in the list then it prints twice. this shouldn' happen

Answer (score 0):

You can try without any external library :

```
a = [1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1]


track=[]
full_track=[]

for i,j in enumerate(a):

    try:
        if a[i+1]==a[i]:
            track.append(j)
        else:
            track.append(a[i])

            full_track.append(track)

            track=[]

    except IndexError:
        if a[i-1]==a[i]:

            track.append(j)
            full_track.append(track)

print(list(map(lambda x:(x[0],x[-1]),full_track)))
```

output:

```
[(1, 1), (0, 0), (1, 1), (0, 0), (1, 1)]
```

Comment: `itertools` is not an external library. It is part of standard library

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> from itertools import groupby, islice
>>> a = [1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1]
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(islice(g, 2) for k, g in groupby(a)))
[1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1]
```